# Use jwt library in Lagom with Java api

Tags: gradle, sbt, jwt, lagom

I want to use a JWT library in Lagom but I'm not certain what library to use. I use Lagom with the Java api.

I found:

- Java libraries, but they are all exposed through gradle
- Scala libraries, but I'm not sure how to use them when I make use of the Java api in Lagom.

Any help?

Comment: I am not sure I understand the question. Presumably you're using Maven if it's a java project... but dependencies and their management tools are divorced -- you should be able to any java library with Maven.

Comment: Also, I think the recommended JWT lib for Java + Play is [jjwt](https://github.com/jwtk/jjwt). For more info, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47335787/2883245).

Comment: @erip I initially used Lagom with the Java api and sbt as build tool as recommended but the refactoring to Maven seems painless.

Comment: You can use any JVM build tool with any JVM language: Gradle with Scala, Maven with Kotlin, SBT with Java.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that using Maven would be the most obvious solution since Lagom supports it now.
Alternatively I'd guess there would be a way to integrate a scala plugin, build with sbt and link the Java code after compilation.

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this problem, and after a long search and long time spent in this problem, I decided to implement my own mechanism while relying on the oAuth2 standard. I understood the mechanism of oAuth2 and I made my own authentication module. It is not difficult to implement

Answer (score 0):

My previous answer was wrong.
There are two better options:

1) Add the library jar manually as unmanaged dependency in the lib folder
2) https://alvinalexander.com/scala/how-use-maven-repository-library-with-scala-sbt

Quoted:

In your build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies += groupID % artifactID % revision
```

For example:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner</groupId>
    <artifactId>htmlcleaner</artifactId>
    <version>2.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Becomes:

```
libraryDependencies += "net.sourceforge.htmlcleaner" % "htmlcleaner" % "2.2"
```

> As mentioned in other recipes, because SBT and Maven both use Apache Ivy under > the covers, and SBT also uses the standard Maven2 repository as a default 
>   resolver, SBT users can easily use Java libraries that are packaged for Maven.

Glad that I will be able to use sbt after all! :-)